# Filtering specified products based on creating <selected> form. Combining Javascript and PHP to make filter

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, forms

## About code:

So I've made a small database with `MySQL`  which contains `id` and `name` of specified 'system'. Now I have to make some sort of shop filter basing on plain JS and PHP.

Whole process is made to automatically insert `value` into `<option>` form based on taken `id` from database.

### Problem:

It correctly outputs the `<option value='x'>`, with inserting values inside of this option, but I have a problem with making sure client sees `system` that he choose.

#### JavaScript errors:

**It doesn't show any error, also it doesn't work.**

#### PHP and MySQL:

Actions for database will be like that:

`SELECT * FROM 'elements' WHERE 'system' = 'y';`

`SELECT * FROM 'elements' WHERE 'system' = 'x';`

`SELECT * FROM 'elements' WHERE 'system' = 'z';`

`SELECT * FROM 'elements' WHERE 'system' = 'q';`

#### JavaScript + Html:

```
<thead>
    
        <select id="systems" name="systems">
        <?php include 'scaffolding-calculator.php'; ?>
        <button name="order" id="order">Change</button>
        </select>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        
        let orderButton = document.getElementById("order");
         let itemList = document.getElementById("systems");
          let outputBox = document.getElementById("output");
        
        orderButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          let collection = itemList.selectedOptions;
            let output = "";
        
            for(let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) {
              if (output === "") {
                  output = "Choose your system: ";
              }
              output += collection[i].label;
              
              if (i === (collection.length - 2) && (collection.length < 3)) {
                  output += " and ";
                } else if (i < (collection.length - 2)) {
                  output += ", ";
                } else if (i === (collection.length - 2)) {
                  outpu += ", and ";
                }
              if (output === "") {
                  output = "You didn't choose anything!";
              }
              
              outputBox.innerHTML = output;
            }
        }, false);
        </script>
```

#### PHP Code for filtering:

```
<?php
    
                $dbhost = "localhost";
                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "1234";
                $dbname = "data";
                
                $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                $options = 'SELECT * FROM `systems`';
                
                
                if ($connection->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
                }
                # echo "<select>";
                  $category = mysqli_query($connection,$options);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($category) > 0) {
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($category)){
                        
                        echo "<option value=".$row['sysid'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
                        
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                # echo "</select><br>";
                
            mysqli_close($connection);
    ?>
```

#### PHP Code for outputting elements:

```
      <?php
            # Database connection
                $dbhost = "localhost";
                $dbuser = "root";
                $dbpass = "1234";
                $dbname = "data";
                
                $connection = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
                if ($connection->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
                }
                #echo "Connection successfull!";
                
                # Questions for Database
                $all = 'SELECT * FROM `elements`';

                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $all);
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                        //output data each row
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            echo "<tr><td>"."<input style='background-color: powderblue;' type='number' class='pcs-input' data-weight='".$row["weight"]."' value='0' min='0' max='999'/></td>";
                            echo "<td>".$row['system']."</td><td>".$row["fullname"]."</td><td>".$row["weight"]."kg</td><td class='sum-weight2'></td></tr>";
                        }
                      } else {
                        echo "0 Results";
                }
        #Declaring JavaScript Code inside PHP
                mysqli_close($connection);
      ?>
```

Comment: Please specify what the actual question is. It's a bit unclear at the moment. Where exactly are you stuck? Sending the value to PHP from JS? Using the value in the query? What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? What doesn't work? What is the expected behavior and what actually happens? What debugging have you done so far? I don't see you trying to make any SQL query with any WHERE clause anywhere?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm stuck in sending value to PHP from JS form, `<button id='order'>Change</button>` doesn't even show, so I can't even check if it works how it supposed to, as I mentioned in the post, **JavaScript doesn't show any error** so, I don't even know what could be wrong there.

Comment: If you don't even see the button, it's probably because you've added it inside the `<select> ... </select>`. You need to add it after the `</select>`. You can't nest any HTML element inside any other HTML element. HTML has rules.